# Checking user ip address after redirect

Tags: perl, redirect

As part of a session security feature I am checking `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}` to make sure the users IP is the same during the whole stay on a website.

Some parts of the website show a waiting screen, if for example the rendering of a file takes some seconds, and I redirect the user to a result screen by the use of a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="$time; URL=…">`.

Unfortunately after this redirect the `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}` variable does not return the users IP but the one from the server.

Is there something I am missing to get this to work properly and/or are there alternatives I could use to redirect the user?

For various reasons htaccess or http-header redirects are not an option and I don't want to use JavaScript for this.

I am already using a 'click me' button to allow the user to manually skipping the wait.

Comment: *Unfortunately after this redirect the $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} variable does not return the users IP but the one from the server.* — That really shouldn't happen (unless you are redirecting to some kind of proxy server)

Comment: Redirecting to the same server, just some different url parameters, sometimes even only refreshing the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the accesslogs … it was actually a different script executed on the server, therefore having the servers IP, which caused all this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to alter between temporary/permanent type of redirect. Check in server logs, the the http code is 301 or 302?